# Is there any other way to implement this lengthy immplemented function using python lists or any other functionality?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, optimization, data-cleaning

I am working on cleaning the Twitter data which contains the "user_location" column. I want to make this **column data uniform by removing the names of regions, cities, states and replacing them with the respective country**. I was doing this manually. Is there any other way to do the same? My code is working good, but I want to optimize it if there is any other way. It's a brute force approach and even making my code too lengthy.

```
def location_fixer(location):
    if location == '22.549709,88.401162':
        return "India"
    
    elif type(location) == str:
     
        if "India" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Hindustan" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Bharat" in location:
            return "India"  
        if "Ahmedabad" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Bhubaneswar" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Pune" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Guwahati" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Jammu" in location:
            return "India"
        if "Delhi" in location:
            return "India"
        if "india" in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Mumbai' in location:
            return 'India'
        if 'New Delhi' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Bangalore' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Bengaluru' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Hyderabad' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Chennai' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Kolkata' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'hyderabad' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'भारत' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Chandigarh' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'BENGALURU' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Lucknow' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Kanpur' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Assam' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Goa' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Gujarat' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Bhopal' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Calicut Beach, Calicut, Kerala' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'Madras' in location:
            return "India"
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  
            
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  
        if 'pune' in location:
            return "India"  

        
        if "Pakistan" in location:
            return "Pakistan"
        if "Hipokrichhistan" in location:
            return "Pakistan"   
            
        if "Baku" in location:
            return "Azerbaijan"
        
        if "Ireland" in location:
            return "Ireland"
        if "Dublin, OH" in location:
            return "Ireland"
        
        if 'Thailand' in location:
            return "Thailand"
        
        if "Nepal" in location:
            return "Nepal"
        
        if 'UAE' in location:
            return "UAE"
        if 'Dubai' in location:
            return "UAE"
                
        if 'Quezon City' in location:
            return "Philippines"
        if 'Dasma Cavite' in location:
            return "Philippines"
        if 'Tagum City' in location:
            return "Philippines"
        if 'Butuan City,  Philippines' in location:
            return "Philippines"
        if 'Butuan City,  Philippines' in location:
            return "Philippines"
        
        if 'Butuan City,  Philippines' in location:
            return "Philippines"

            
            
        if 'Al Farwaniya, Kuwait' in location:
            return "Kuwait"
        if 'Kuwait' in location:
            return "Kuwait"
        
        if 'Bangladesh' in location:
            return "Bangladesh"
        
        if 'Sri Lanka' in location:
            return "Sri Lanka"
       
        if 'Amsterdam' in location:
            return "The Netherlands"
        
        if 'Kenya' in location:
            return "Kenya"
       
        if 'Belgium' in location:
            return "Belgium"
        
        if 'İstanbul' in location:
            return "Turkey"

          
        if 'Beijing' in location:
            return "China"
        if 'Hong Kong' in location:
            return "China"
        if 'Shanghai' in location:
            return "China"
        if 'Macau' in location:
            return "China"

        if 'TEHRAN' in location:
            return "Iran"    
        
        if 'Berlin' in location:
            return "Germany"
            
    

        if 'USA' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'U.S.A.' in location:
            return "United States"  
        if 'NY' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'MD' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'DC' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'TX' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'CA' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'Atlanta' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'Los Angeles' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'IN' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'New York' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'SC' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'The North' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'MO' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'California' in location:
            return 'United States'
        if 'PA' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'MA' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'WA' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Massachusetts' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'KS' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'San Francisco' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Texas' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Illinois' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'IL' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'NC' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'VA' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'America' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'AZ' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'NV' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'CO' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Florida' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Nashville' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'D.C. Metro' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Bethesda, Maryland' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Brookfield, WI' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Somerset, NJ' in location:
            return "United States"
            
        if 'Brookfield, WI' in location:
            return "United States"
        if 'Brookfield, WI' in location:
            return "United States"
        

            

    
        
        if 'Melbourne' in location:
            return "Australia"
        if 'Australia' in location:
            return "Australia"
        if 'Sydney' in location:
            return "Australia"
        if 'Brisbane' in location:
            return "Australia"
        
        
        if 'London' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'England' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'northampton, middle england' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'UK' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'Manchester' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'Sheffield & Leeds' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'Stoke-on-Trent' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'Scotland, United Kingdom' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"     
        if 'Glasgow' in location:
            return "United Kingdom"
        if 'lincolnshire, uk' in location:
            return "United Kingdom" 
            

        
        if 'Canada' in location:
            return "Canada"
        if 'Toronto' in location:
            return "Canada"
        if 'Ontario' in location:
            return "Canada"
        if 'Vancouver, British Columbia' in location:
            return "Canada" 
            

 


        else:
            return location
    else:
        return location
```

This function is working fine. It would be a great help if someone can guide me to optimize it or provide a short trick to do the same. I am quite a newbie so unaware of this.
So basically I want to implement something like this; where the words in the list may be present as a substring and not an exact full string.

```
if ["india", "India", "Bharat", "Gujarat"] in location:
            return "India"
```

Comment: What does a complete `location` string look like?

Comment: You can cut half your code by converting location to lower case.  You can store all of your city/country mappings in a dictionary and do a `for` loop on that list.  However, you need to be aware of how fallible substring matches are.  "India" is going to match "Indiana" and "Indianapolis".  The two-letter US state codes are hopeless; "CA" will match "Canada", "CO" will match "Colombia" and "Scotland". And, by the way, "Dublin, OH" is in the US, not in Ireland.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for correcting the data. Also, I need to look up to these problems carefully, wasn't aware of this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work for you

```
fList = []
fList.append({'filter':["india", "Bharat", "Gujarat"], 
              'to':'India' })

fList.append({'filter':["Quezon", "Dasma Cavite", "Tagum", 
                         "Butuan", "philippines"],
              'to':'Philippines' })

def filterLocation(loc, filterList):
    for f in filterList:
        if any([(i.lower() in loc.lower()) for i in f['filter']]):
            return f['to']
    return loc
```

This saves you a lot of for, if and returns. Here is an example:

```
location1 = 'india something'
location2 = 'Tagum City foobar'
print(filterLocation(location1, fList))
print(filterLocation(location2, fList))
```

will print

```
India
Philippines
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, this is really helpful, I just removed the lower() function, because it might create the undesired mapping.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I just added a default return value, in case no filter applies.